# Return path of directory that contains given input string in its name in nodejs

Tags: node.js

So I have a directories say, 001-cat, 002-dog, 003-bird etc.

I want to get full path of 001-cat if I input cat.
Or 002-dog if input is dog.
How to do it in nodejs?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is to change the names of the folders. Or read all the directory names in the folder. Assuming the number-name is consistent I can try to get path of each directory and store it as an associative array {cat: cat path, dog: dog path}